# how i open an image from device gallery and put it into <img> element. i am using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using J-Query mobile. Where i want to insert an image into  element in my html page from device gallery.

i did enough google but did't find any solution. Please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The W3C recommendation can be found here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/

A small example that will let you select an image. On a desktop computer, this lets you browse files/folder for an image file. On a smart phone, it lets you browse your gallery, and if you have a camera, you can shoot a picure directly:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="image">Select image:</label>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" accept="image/*" capture>
</div>
<div id="preview"></div>

<script>
    $(document).on("change", "#image", function(e){
        var file = $(this)[0].files[0];
        if (file.size && file.size > 5242880) {
            alert("The image must be less than 5 MB.");
        }
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            $('#preview').html('<span class="nice">Preview:</span><br/><img src="'+oFREvent.target.result+'" width="250px">');
        };
    });
</script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xncvvvgj/

Note that if you want to save the image permanently, you'll need to post it to a server script. Let me know if you need an example for that.